# Função LEN, saber quantidade de caracteres de um número

Tags: sql, sql-server, funções

No exemplo abaixo o resultado da consulta ao invés de retornar **7** é retornado **5**.

```
DECLARE @valor money = 10.6879

SELECT LEN(@Valor)
```

*A impressão que tenho é que quando o número é do tipo*  `money` *, é considerado somente 2 casas decimais.*

Qual a função eu usaria para retornar o número exato de caracteres de um número do tipo money?

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro crie a função

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.countDigits(@A float) RETURNS tinyint AS
BEGIN
declare @R tinyint
IF @A IS NULL 
   RETURN NULL
set @R = 0
while @A - str(@A, 18 + @R, @r) <> 0
begin
   SET @R = @R + 1
end
RETURN @R
END
GO
```

Depois é só usar

```
SELECT LEN(cast(10.6879 as decimal)) + dbo.countDigits(10.6879) +  + 1 
//número antes da virgula + Número de casas depois da vírgular + 1 = 7
```

Comment: Isso resolveu o meu problema, através dessa função eu sei exatamente o número de caracteres de um número. Se eu convertesse o número para float também resolveria o meu problema?

Answer (score 2):

Converta usando `CONVERT` para o tipo `DECIMAL` ([referência aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)):

```
DECLARE @valor money = 10.6879

SELECT LEN(CONVERT(decimal(6,4),@Valor)); //7
```

Comment: Essa solução funciona, mas como eu faria quando não sei o número de casas decimais do número? Nessa solução você está afirmando que o número terá 4 casas decimais. Gostaria de saber o número de caracteres de um número, independente da quantidade de casas decimais.

Comment: @AdemiltonMarceloNunes por mais que você ja tenha dado certo para o André, vou procurar a solução para a sua pergunta ;)

Comment: Irei remover o certo da resposta do André para aguardar a sua resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A solução para o seu problema é simples:

```
DECLARE @Valor MONEY = 10.6879

SELECT LEN(CONVERT(FLOAT, @Valor)) -- 7
```

A diferença para o exemplo do *@LeonardoBonetti* é o tipo de dados da conversão (`FLOAT` ao invés de `DECIMAL(6, 4)`).